# Find the palindrome numbers of a given range

Tags: python

I want to find the palindrome numbers of a given range of integers without reversing the number. I want to rather check a condition going from digit to digit. If I use an if-else condition I get the numbers for which the condition holds only for one digit and not all of them. In order to make the condition hold for all digits I was tempted to use a while loop. But still I can not get the list of palindromes, the while loop running too long. Can somebody tell me what is wrong and what should I correct ? Thanks. Here is the code:

```
def pal():
    s = []
    for i in range(100, 10000):
        for j in range(len(str(i))):
            while str(i)[j] == str(i)[len(str(i)) - (j+1)]:
                s.append(i)
    return s
print(pal())
```

Comment: This code does `s.append(i)` for every "mirrored" character in `i`.  Instead, it should check that *all* the characters are "mirrored", and only then do `s.append(i)`.  So `s.append(i)` needs to be outside of the innermost `for` loop.  Then your task becomes: how to prevent `s.append(i)` being called if not all the characters are "mirrored".

Comment: Thanks. When I get `s.append(i)` outside the innermost loop, I get an indentation error.

Comment: Right, it's not just a case of unindenting that line :)  It's about reworking the code so that the append is done once-per-i rather than once-per-j.  Jeanot Zubler's answer shows how it can be done.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are calling append for every digit. Something like this is more sensible:

```
def pal():
    palindromes = []
    for i in range(100, 10000):
        s = str(i)
        palindrome = True
        for j in range(len(s)//2):
            if s[j] != s[-(j+1)]:
                palindrome = False
        if palindrome:
            palindromes.append(s)

    return palindromes
```

Edit: I just realised, you also have a while loop that never ends. Replace your while loop with an if statement, and then you see where the problem in your logic is.

Comment: Looks good.  An optimisation (though it's not a big deal for strings of this size) is to `break` out of the inner loop as soon as you set `palindrome = False`.

Comment: As I put it in the text, I first used an if-else statement instead of the while loop. The outcome was false. Instead of checking if a digit is mirrored into itself, you rather check if it doesn't and thus you exclude these. Good idea. How about if you were to check, as I did, if all the digits of a given number are mirrored appropriately and then keep only these ? How one would do that ? This is what I tried and failed.